# PHP Spaces being put in automatically

Tags: php

```
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $name = $row['name'];
    $contents = $row['contents'];
    array_push($allnotes,"<b>",$name,":","</b>",$contents,"<br>   <form action='notes/delete-note.php' method='post'> <input type='hidden' name='removenote' value='",$name,"'> <button type='submit'        class='notedelete'>Delete ",$name,"</button> </form>");
 }
} else {
array_push($allnotes,"No avaliable notes!");
}
```

The problem i have is that the above code (here -> value='",$name,"'>) is adding spaces which in turn breaks it as my other code cant read it properly any idea on how to stop these spaces. Thanks

Comment: This code definitely does not add the spaces. Those are just a bunch of arguments for `array_push().` But I have know idea what you are actually trying to achieve?

Comment: use `trim()` on your vars to kill whitespace.  But as @Rizier123 notes, this code is not adding any spaces.

Comment: I guess that you wanted to concatenate those strings instead of pushing them to `$allnotes` as separate array items. If so, use dots instead of commas.

Comment: thank you the dots fixed it @Jakub Matczak

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you are doing, is the same as:

```
$allnotes[] = "<b>";
$allnotes[] = $name;
$allnotes[] = ":"; 
$allnotes[] = "</b>";
$allnotes[] = $contents; 
$allnotes[] = "<br>   <form action='notes/delete-note.php' method='post'> <input type='hidden' name='removenote' value='"; 
$allnotes[] = $name; 
$allnotes[] = "'> <button type='submit'        class='notedelete'>Delete "; 
$allnotes[] = $name; 
$allnotes[] = "</button> </form>";
```

It seems to me that what you've really wanted was.. (notice the dot operator)

```
$allnotes[] = "<b>".$name.":"."</b>".$contents."<br>   <form action='notes/delete-note.php' method='post'> <input type='hidden' name='removenote' value='".$name."'> <button type='submit'        class='notedelete'>Delete ".$name."</button> </form>";
```